# how to fetch 1 duplicate data in bigquery with criteria

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Please help me !!
Currently I have duplicate phone number data, but there are several duplicate phone numbers that I still want to appear because the phone numbers are input by different users. how to separate the data
I've tried but still can not meet expectations

is an example of duplicate data

| id | user_id | phone_number | created_at | outlet_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | R0004 | 789150 | 2022-10-10T15:58:51 | 1231 |
| 2 | R0005 | 789150 | 2022-06-21T11:44:18 | 1458 |
| 3 | R0006 | 789150 | 2023-01-30T20:08:45 | 1587 |
| 5 | R0007 | 507371 | 2022-03-31T15:21:49 | 1001 |
| 6 | R0007 | 507371 | 2022-03-31T15:21:52 | 1001 |

my expectation is the data that appears will be like below

| id | user_id | phone_number | created_at | outlet_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | R0004 | 789150 | 2022-10-10T15:58:51 | 1231 |
| 2 | R0005 | 789150 | 2022-06-21T11:44:18 | 1458 |
| 3 | R0006 | 789150 | 2023-01-30T20:08:45 | 1587 |
| 5 | R0007 | 507371 | 2022-03-31T15:21:49 | 1001 |

why because the phone number 789150 was input by a different user so it doesn't matter, but for 507371 it was input by the same user so I have to take only 1

I've tried using a query like this but it only retrieves the max id

```
select 
distinct ll.id 
,ll.user_id
,ll.phone_number
,ll.created_at
,ll.outlet_id
from `my_table` ll
and ll.id  in (select max(id) from my_table group by phone_number)
and ll.phone_number in ('+62-8999789150','+62-8999507371')
order by 3 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below.

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(t HAVING MIN created_at).* 
  FROM `my_table` t
 GROUP BY t.user_id, t.phone_number, t.outlet_id;
```

**Query results**

[image]

**See also**

- [HAVING MIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate-function-calls#having_min)

Answer (score 0):

You can concat "user_id" and "phone_number" columns to check duplicated rows like that;

```
SELECT 
        CONCAT(ll.user_id, '_', ll.phone_number),
        COUNT(1)
    FROM  `my_table` ll
    GROUP BY CONCAT(ll.user_id, '_', ll.phone_number)
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

to get duplicated rows;

```
SELECT *
    FROM  `my_table` ll2
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 
            CONCAT(ll.user_id, '_', ll.phone_number) concat_value,
            MIN(ll.created_at) created_at
        FROM  `my_table` ll
        GROUP BY CONCAT(ll.user_id, '_', ll.phone_number)
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
               ) ll ON ll.concat_value = CONCAT(ll2.user_id, '_', ll2.phone_number) AND ll.created_at != ll2.created_at
```